# How to send authentication headers with jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the domainAPI site (which is free so far) to handle domain availability checking. Their brief documentation is [here](http://www.domainapi.com/documentation/how-to-use-domainapi/servuces-provided/domain-availability-api.html).

I'm new to most of this so I may be overlooking something obvious. The second part of the header is my username and password, encrypted as base64 in the format username:password. If I access the url directly, that same username and password successfully gives me access.

The code I have so far is the following, which still fails:

```
$('#domain').keyup(function() {
    $("#loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.domainapi.com/v1/availability/example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function() { alert("Success"); },
        error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
        beforeSend: function setHeader(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ZW1iZXJza2VjaDp6eWFrc21hdnNvenY=');}
    });
});
```

Comment: usually, headers are set on Server-side (like php). Cause authentication requires some server checks and session set.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into cross-domain issues here.

AJAX requests can only be performed cross-domain if the server has CORS-support (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing for more info) enabled, and a quick check on `api.domainapi.com` doesn't suggest it does. If you open your browser's console, you should get an error message saying as much.

To solve this, you'll need to implement some sort of proxy on your own server (which, because it runs on the same domain as your web page, should be usable as AJAX 'target'), which in turn will forward requests to `api.domainapi.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand what you are saying I think. Make a php page that access the domainapi site, and use ajax to access that page. The domainapi site gives me some headers to use to make the request, but I'm not exactly sure how to make a php page that does this. Do I need to use cURL or something? This is what I have:

    <?php

  header("GET /encrypted-area HTTP/1.1");
  header("Host: api.domainapi.com/v1/availability/freedomain.com");
  header("Authorization: Basic ZW1iZXJza2VjaDp6eWFrc21hdnNvenY=");
  
?>

Comment: If you're always using your own username/password to check for domain availability, pass the domain to check using a `$.ajax` request to your PHP-page, perform the request from PHP to `api.domainapi.com` (using cURL sounds okay, but I don't do PHP), and return the results (so `$.ajax` can process it).